# Auto Increment width of an input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to code an counter.

Here is my  [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssxx8/1/)

```
$('.substract-value').click(function(){
    val = $('#how-many').val();
    if (val == 1) 
        { }
    else
        $('#how-many').val(val-1);
});
$('.add-value').click(function(){
    val = $('#how-many').val();
    $('#how-many').val(parseInt(val)+1);
});
```

I want the size of the input tag to auto-increment when the content inside the input tag will become 2digit or 3digit.

is it possible only with css.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript) should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution in this case would be not to use input tag, instead replace it with span tag. span is an inline element and the width will auto increment based on its content.

As i am moving to span, the jquery will change. and instead of `val()` we should use `text()`

Demo fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ssxx8/11/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something roughly similar to this:

```
$(function() {
    var $howMany = $('#how-many'); // cache that

    $('.substract-value').click(function(){
        var val = $howMany.val();
        if (val == 1) { }
        else {
            $howMany.val(val-1);
            checkSize(val);
        }
    });
    $('.add-value').click(function(){
        var val = $('#how-many').val();
        $howMany.val(parseInt(val)+1);
        checkSize(val);
    });

    function checkSize(v) {
        if ( v > 9 ) {
            $howMany.css('width', '80px');
        } else if ( v < 9 ) {
            $howMany.css('width', '20px');
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: want a css solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.substract-value').click(function(){
    val = $('#how-many').val();
    if (val == 1) { }
    else
        $('#how-many').val(val-1);

   setWidth();
});
$('.add-value').click(function(){
    val = $('#how-many').val();
    $('#how-many').val(parseInt(val)+1);
    setWidth();
});


 var oneLetterWidth = 10;

 var minCharacters = 2;

 function setWidth() {
     var len = $("#how-many").val().length;
     if (len > minCharacters) {
         // increase width
         $("#how-many").width(len * oneLetterWidth);
     } else {
         // restore minimal width;
         $("#how-many").width(50);
     }
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ssxx8/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.substract-value').click(function(){
    val = $('#how-many').val();
    if (val == 1) { }
    else
        $('#how-many').val(val-1);
    updateWidth(); 
});

$('.add-value').click(function(){
    val = $('#how-many').val();
    $('#how-many').val(parseInt(val)+1);
    updateWidth();
});

function updateWidth(){
    size = $('#how-many').val().length;
    size = size*7; // average width of a char is 7px
    $('#how-many').css('width',size);  
}
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/ssxx8/9/

Comment: My question? Sorry did not get you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to approach this way:

```
var obj = $('#how-many');
$('.substract-value').click(function () {
    var content = obj.val();
    if (content > 1) 
        obj.val(parseInt(obj.val()) - 1);
    obj.css("width", (obj.val().length * 10) + "px");
});
$('.add-value').click(function () {
    obj.val(parseInt(obj.val()) + 1);
    obj.css("width", (obj.val().length * 10) + "px");
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/9npVV/)**